# C# - Serialize Object to constant variable or use directly in test case with NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a problem when I try to serialize an object to constant a variable or use serialized object inside a test case.

I try to do something like this:

```
    [TestCase(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject), TestName = "Test Case Name")]
    public void Test(string someString)
    {
         do something...
    }
```

But, I get an error that I need use only constant variables.
I need something like this:

```
 public const string someString2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

Then, I can use this someString2 inside the test case.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: In Attributes are only constants allowed. If you want something that gets computed at runtime switch to TestCaseSource Attribut and let the input for the test be delivered by a method.

Answer (score 1):

JsonConvert.SerializeObject() is never constant, it is a runtime routine.

Constant means known at compile-time. If myObject itself never changes, and it is small and simple you could just pass the json into the attribute as a static string, i.e.

```
[TestCase(@"{""foo"": ""bar""}, TestName = "Test Case Name")]
```

Or you can just pass the object as a parameter in the method, and call JsonConvert.SerializeObject() as the first statement and get your json that way.